# Using chef array attribute within bash resource

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am having  `node['server']['ipaddress']` attribute that includes 3 ip addresses as below:

```
node['server']['ipaddress']=["10.211.241.21", "10.211.241.20", "10.211.241.22"]
```

I am now trying to use the above values in a chef bash resource

```
bash 'configure_engine_discovery' do
  code <<-EOH
  echo `docker run --server ipaddress1 --server ipaddress2 --server ipaddress3 --update`
  EOH
end
```

There might be more than 3 ipaddresses and I want to make the above bash command more dynamic so that the I don't require to change the bash every time and it can accommodate any number of server ips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
server_specs = node['server']['ipaddress'].map { |s| "--server #{s}" }.join(' ')
command = "docker run #{server_specs} --update"
echo command
```

By the way, why isn't the key named in the plural, `ipaddresses` instead of `ipaddress`?  That's confusing to readers.